# Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified with AWS

Tags: java, intellij-idea, aws-cli

Getting issue `Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified` while executing java program from intellij but when executing same command from cmd prompt then it's working properly.

```
public class TestRunProgram {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String commandRun = "aws apigateway get-api-keys --profile awsProdUser --region eu-west-1";
    System.out.println(commandRun);
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec(commandRun);
}}
```

Getting below issue after execution

```
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "aws": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
```

Comment: Does it help to change your command to "cmd /c aws apigateway get-api-keys --profile awsProdUser --region eu-west-1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution after installing AWS CLI for windows. Initially, I was installing it from python.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-windows.html